# searching for columns containing at least one value from another column using full-text search

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I have a MySQL database with table and column names unknown in advance.

There is a table table_column_info, which contains the names of the tables and columns that need to be worked with.

There is an email_mapping table with system user logins.

I need to go through each table from table_column_info and check if at least one value from the login column is contained in the corresponding table column.

If there is at least one match in the table, then write the name of the table and column to the logins_map table.

I wrote the following procedure however it stops executing after going through the first column even if no value was found

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createEmailMap()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tableName, columnName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE current_value VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE found INT;

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name, column_name FROM table_column_info;
    DECLARE cur_values CURSOR FOR SELECT old_email FROM email_mapping;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;

-- 1st cursor for columns
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO tableName, columnName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        OPEN cur_values;

--2nd cursor for logins
        values_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur_values INTO current_value;
            IF current_value IS NULL THEN
                LEAVE values_loop;
            END IF;

            SET found = 0;
            SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT 1 INTO @found FROM ', tableName, ' WHERE MATCH (', columnName, ') AGAINST (\'"', current_value, '"\' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 1');
            SELECT @query;
            PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

            IF @found = 1 THEN
                INSERT INTO email_map (table_name, column_name) VALUES (tableName, columnName);
                SELECT @found, tableName, columnName;
                LEAVE values_loop;
            END IF;

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE cur_values;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;

END //
```